# is it defined behaviour to add the result of logical operation

Tags: c, relational-operators

Is it okay (defined behavior) to add up the result of logical operations (as they should just be `0` or `1`)?

Can I do something like this if I want to count the numbers bigger than zero?(or is there a better way?)

```
int a[3] = {1,-5,3};
int result  = 0;
for( int i = 0 ; i<3; i++)
{
    result += a[i]>0;
}
```

Comment: `a[i]>0` is 0 or 1. yes it's defined.

Comment: Yes it is perfectly fine code. All boolean operations such as the relational operators are guaranteed to return an `int` with value 1 or 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.8, (*emphasis mine*)

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=`
>   (greater than or equal to) **shall yield `1` if the specified relation is true and `0` if it is
>   false.<sup>107)</sup> The result has type `int`.**

Then you're performing a compound assignment, where it is required that

> For the operators `+=` and `-=` only, either the left operand shall be an atomic, qualified, or
>   unqualified pointer to a complete object type, and the right shall have integer type; or **the
>   left operand shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right
>   shall have arithmetic type.**

and your expression satisfies the constraint.

So yes, it is defined behaviour.

---

That said, from a syntax perspective, you're only safe because of the default [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) matches your expectation. There's no problem as such, but being explicit (and thus, sure) never hurts.

You can rewrite the expression as

```
 result += ( a[i] > 0 );
```

Comment: Do you know where to find relevant parts of the standard on the top of your head? or how can you be so fast?^^

Comment: @KamiKaze All operator groups are listed in chapter 6.5 so it is just a matter of opening the pdf and click on the relevant group :)

Comment: @Lundin I think I will ditch the next book I want to read and read the full standard instead. That way I know where to find what

Comment: @StoryTeller: Fixed the double negative :-).

Comment: @sleske With all due respect, that double negative was **not** a typo. Standard mentions the term "undefined behaviour", but it never mentions "defined behaviour", only implies.

Comment: @KamiKaze - The standard is a really bad resource to *learn* the language if you wish to do it fast. You'd be better served to finish the book first, and then graduate to the standard.

Comment: @StoryTeller Do I sound like that I need to learn the language? (honest question) On what parts would you deduct that? Because I am not reading a book about programming at the moment I thought my skills in C were a good basis at least. (Or did you just assumed it because of my book statement, As I said this is an honest question If I have deficits I have to remove I am glad to learn about those)

Comment: @KamiKaze - Meant no offence. I (perhaps erroneously) deduced from you yourself saying *"I think I will ditch the next book I want to read and read the full standard instead"*.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Sorry, no disrespect intended. It just that, as pointed out by StoryTeller, "not undefined" sounds weird in English. It's true the standard never mentions "defined behavior", but that's probably just because any behavior described in the standard is by definition defined. Also, many texts on C use the expression "behavior is defined" or similar. Anyway, feel free to change it back if you feel it is clearer that way.

Comment: @sleske Nothing to be sorry for, was just trying to point out that the other version was also "conforming". I'll leave it to other language-lawyers to have a look at it. :)